# I cannot login to my raspberry after uninstalling zsh

Tags: pi-4, apt, bash, login, root

Raspberry is running fine, but I cannot login via ssh or directly on the device. Problem: I executed following command: sudo apt remove --purge zsh

Yes I know I am a moron.

I know I have to access /etc/passwd to change after my username the entry from /bin/zsh zu /bin/bash. But I cannot access this file. When I add init /bin/bash to cmdline.txt I have sort of root access. I can read but not write.

And: Booting the rasperry holding shift does not bring me to the boot menu

Anyone can help me?

Comment: re-install? ...

Comment: `Anyone can help me?` is not a question  about  the  problem

Comment: What OS? What did you ACTUALLY do? There is no need to purge ANYTHING; you can have multiple shells and use for different purposes. There are methods to login to a root shell and repair but you easiest option would be to reinstall.

Comment: I don't know where you found the strange things you tried - do not blindly follow stuff you find; most of it is wrong.

Comment: `I can read but not write` - I guess `/` is mounted readonly - you could `mount / -o remount,rw` to make it writable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting to a root shell can repair most configuration problems on the Pi.

1. Append `init=/bin/sh` at the end of `cmdline.txt` and reboot.
2. After booting you will be at the prompt in a root shell.
3. Your root file system is mounted as readonly now, so remount it as read/write
   `mount -n -o remount,rw /`
4. Edit to fix your problem.
5. Remove `init=/bin/sh` and reboot.

NOTE you should use `init=/bin/sh` NOT `init=/bin/bash` as this is guaranteed to exist.
On Debian `/bin/sh` is actually a link to `/bin/dash`